# How many times is color used in Schindler's List?

Tags: schindlers-list

There are multiple descriptions of "The Girl in Red" on this site, but I remember color being used in *Schindler's List* more than only that one time. Is my mind playing tricks on me? If it isn't, is there a theme to the multiple times that selective color is used?

Comment: I specifically remember a purple flower in the mud of one of the concentration camps, but I suspect this is a fever dream.

Answer (score 2):

During the movie the only color is the red coat of the little girl.  Specifically so you are aware of it and it is in contrast to everything else.  I believe she appears twice, once when 'escaping' and again when you see her in the pile of the dead being burnt.

At the end the film becomes colorized as the descendants of those Schindler saved place stones on his grave.

Small caveat, I always thought that the candle that is lit when the list is first being started was in color as well.

Comment: The movie does start in color and fades to black and white as the flames die out. I'm not sure what your source is, but here's a clip of the beginning of the movie. Shifts to black and white at 1:06. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24fwJMLsyNs

Comment: I had forgotten about the opening, but that would explain what I was thinking about.  It is only my own recollection, so not entirely sure - in a later scene when the list is being discussed a candle is lit and I always though it was in color; it would have been a reference back to the beginning of the movie and the candle flame in color then as well, both "beginnings".

Answer (score 2):

4 times + ending

1. Candle at the beginning
2. Girl in red
3. Girl in red (dead) at the crematoriums
4. Candle at the ending
5. Ending (Schindler´s Jews and descendants)

Comment: Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer may include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, and/or adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found. I hope you enjoy participating.